# Passing a function to Start-Job

Tags: function, powershell, start-job

So after succeeding in passing variables to start-job(huge thanks to the awesome stackoverflow members).
Now I'm struggling to pass a function into the job.
I need to use the Append-ColoredLine function inside the 7zipextraction job.
For some reason I cant find a way of achieving that.

```
function Append-ColoredLine
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox]$box,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [System.Drawing.Color]$color,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [string]$text
    )
    $box.SelectionStart = $box.TextLength
    $box.SelectionLength = 0
    $box.SelectionColor = $color
    $box.AppendText($text)
    $box.AppendText([Environment]::NewLine)
    
}


$OutputDirectory="C:\Test\2"
$zipfile="C:\Test\2\1.zip"
$uploadevidence="C:\UploadFolder"


function 7zipextraction
{
  Set-Alias 7zip $using:7zip_path
# Extracting files
$extract = 7zip x -y $using:zpfile -o"${using:OutputDirectory}"
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
    
   Append-ColoredLine $using:richtextbox1 Red "$using:Time 7zip Error"
    
    return
  }
  else
  {
    Append-ColoredLine $using:richtextbox1 Blue "$using:Time Files extracted successfully"
  }
   Start-Sleep -s 2

  }

 Start-Job -Name zip2 -ScriptBlock ${Function:7zipextraction} | Receive-Job -Wait
```

Comment: This is never going to work - PowerShell won't be able to serialize Windows Forms components for use in the child process, and the code executing in your job won't have access to write back to the form. Either handle coloring of the output once you _retrieve_ the output from the job, or switch strategy completely and [execute your code in a separate runspace or runspace pool](https://kamikazeadmin.net/2021/10/21/how-to-build-a-colourful-gui-for-powershell-using-winforms-runspacepools-and-hash-tables/) within the same process

Comment: Thanks… I have suspected that this is a no go. I will try reading the job status or finding alternative for running jobs in the background so that the win form window won’t freeze.

Comment: You can still use jobs. Just output plain text messages from within the job, possibly with color information, e. g. `"red;$using:Time 7zip Error"` and use `ForEach-Object` at the end of the `Start-Job` pipeline to call `Append-ColoredLine`.